# Return result of query from function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the query for example "select id, field1, field2 from table1" (id and field1 are integer and field2 is varchar) and I need call the query from function and return result as is.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_record()
  RETURNS TABLE(id integer , field2 varchar(20)) AS
$$                                                  
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'SELECT table1.id, table1.field2 FROM table1' INTO id, field2;
    RETURN;
END;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

but this solution returns only one record in one field. How can I correct it?

Comment: You'll want to use `RETURN QUERY` instead of `EXECUTE '...' INTO`.

Comment: JNevill, but if I use RETURN QUERY instead of EXECUTE '...' INTO the function return all records in one field like text "(value1, value2)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_record(OUT id integer, OUT field2 varchar(20))
RETURNS SETOF record
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT table1.id, table1.field2 FROM tiers;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I need function without parameters

Comment: @ViKo Function without parameters returning rowset called `view` ;) Seriously `out` parameters just provides result structure and you should use this function like `select * from get_all_record()` without parameters specifying. @PeterEisentraut your example can be simplified a bit using `language sql` instead of `plpgsql`.